# Objective-J: Parse error when init custom obj

Tags: objective-j

I come from a Cocoa background, so I'm familiar with how Objective-j should work.

When I create a custom object, seen here:

https://gist.github.com/800413

I get a parse error, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the missing space between alloc] and init on line 25.